# What do the parameters in the NTP response mean?

Tags: systemd, time, ntp

When I add the following line to the `systemd-timesyncd.service` :

```
Environment="SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug"
```

I get the following output when syncing the system time:

```
systemd-timesyncd[42507]: Sent NTP request to 46.175.224.7:123 (0.pl.pool.ntp.org).
systemd-timesyncd[42507]: NTP response:
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   leap         : 0
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   version      : 4
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   mode         : 4
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   stratum      : 3
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   precision    : 0.000002 sec (-19)
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   root distance: 0.069962 sec
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   reference    : n/a
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   origin       : 1569357097.226
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   receive      : 1569357097.254
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   transmit     : 1569357097.254
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   dest         : 1569357097.292
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   offset       : -0.005 sec
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   delay        : +0.066 sec
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   packet count : 4
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   jitter       : 0.016
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   poll interval: 512
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   adjust (slew): -0.005 sec
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   status       : 8193 sync
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   time now     : 1569357097.292
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   constant     : 5
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   offset       : -0.005 sec
systemd-timesyncd[42507]:   freq offset  : +796760 (+12 ppm)
systemd-timesyncd[42507]: interval/delta/delay/jitter/drift 512s/-0.005s/0.066s/0.016s/+12ppm
systemd-timesyncd[42507]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/timesync1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
```

So basically, what do all the parameters in the NTP response mean?

Answer (score 1):

Some of those are trivial (e.g. "version 4" means it's version 4 of the NTP protocol), but a lot of those aren't so trivial. For example, leap 0 means that the server isn't warning of an impending leap second (values 2 = adding a second or 3 = removing a second) or an unsynchronized clock (value 4). Mode 4 is server; stratum is basically how many hops the server is away from a reference (national standard) clock.

For full details of all the fields & how they're used, refer to [RFC 5905](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5905) and its updates. Also the various [ntp working group documents](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/ntp/documents/).